# Multi variables by links

Tags: php, variables, button, get, html-lists

I'm making a news archive.
I want the news archive to have several options.
At first I want the archive to have the option to only display news posted in a certain year and an option to display only news thats posted in a certain category.
These features are both saved in my database at every post so with a small php code I can easily find posts created in e.g 2013.

The problem is is that I want to make buttons in my news archive. Buttons that can make the user decide which feature is enabled or not (if you understand what I'm saying). I want the users to have the ability to make sure only posts of e.g 2013 appear on their screen but on the same time only posts of e.g sport news appear. 
By making two features for the user to enable, I couldn't think of a way linking them to the correct page.

If they click on a specific year they will go to article.php?year=2013 for example. But if you also want to use the other feature (category) it's impossible because you will be send to article.php?category=sport for example and the posts will no longer be searched on their published year but only on their category.

I want to make sure that if one feature/option is already enabled the other will only add &category=sport at the end of the URL so the URL becomes article.php?year=2013&category=sport which makes sure the user can select multiple features at the same time.

```
   <ul class="archive">
            <li>
            <div>Year</div>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="article.php?year=all">Every year</a></li>
            <li><a href="article.php?year=2013">2013</a></li>
            <li><a href="article.php?year=2012">2012</a></li>
            <li><a href="article.php?year=2011">2011</a></li>
            <li><a href="article.php?year=2010">2010</a></li>
     </ul>
        </li>
          </ul>
    <ul class="archive">
            <li>
            <div>Category</div>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="?category=all">General news</a></li>
            <li><a href="article.php?category=sport">Sport news</a></li>
            <li><a href="article.php?category=international">International news</a></li>
            <li><a href="article.php?category=national">National news</a></li>

        </ul>
        </li>
          </ul>
```

I hope you understand my problem and look forward to hear from some of you!

Comment: You mean , only the selected **UL(unordered lists)** should be displayed on screen and this should be controlled by user?

Comment: Yes, the user can select wether they only want to see posts that are post in a specific year or posts in a specific catogory. The problem is, is that if the user wants to select both features it's impossible because the ul's will not link to article.php?year=(specific year)&category=(specific catogory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic solution (lazy too) could be dragging around all your possible parameters with empy values when not needed, so for example you would have:

```
<ul class="archive">
            <li>
            <div>Year</div>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="article.php?year=all&category=<?=$_GET['category']?>">Every year</a></li>
            <li><a href="article.php?year=2013&category=<?=$_GET['category']?>">2013</a></li>
            <li><a href="article.php?year=2012&category=<?=$_GET['category']?>">2012</a></li>
            <li><a href="article.php?year=2011&category=<?=$_GET['category']?>">2011</a></li>
            <li><a href="article.php?year=2010&category=<?=$_GET['category']?>">2010</a></li>
     </ul>
        </li>
          </ul>
    <ul class="archive">
            <li>
            <div>Category</div>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="?category=all&year=<?=$_GET['year']?>">General news</a></li>
            <li><a href="article.php?category=sport&year=<?=$_GET['year']?>">Sport news</a></li>
            <li><a href="article.php?category=international&year=<?=$_GET['year']?>">International news</a></li>
            <li><a href="article.php?category=national&year=<?=$_GET['year']?>">National news</a></li>

        </ul>
        </li>
          </ul>
```

Anyway I reccomend that you build some sort of automatic menù generator, so you can add parameters and links without too much effort, for example via a "link generator" which will append the needed parameters (I'll put in a snippet for this if you need).

Comment: Thanks very much! I'm going to try it out. It seems like the solution!

Comment: @TomGroot You're welcome... :) (It is A solution, not THE solution, since it's lazy and on the long run it will take you lots of time every time you want to add a new option... :P)